# Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, voting

Is there a way to see who voted (upvotes and/or downvotes) on your answers and/or questions?

Comment: Votes are anonymous by design and there are features available to mods and devs to spot vote fraud.

Comment: @Scrooge is right, but if you sense strange voting behavior, don't hesitate to flag or contact administrators.

Comment: I want to know who has eaten my last cookie, the one I kept for a special occasion!

Comment: Any time you see truly suspicious up-votes, **flag for moderation**. Give a concise, detailed, description of what you find odd about the situation. Moderators _do_ look for "sock puppets" to prevent reputation inflation and the flags help to keep things honest. Feel free to downvote bad questions and answers, too. Every bit helps.

Comment: See also [Revealing Identity of those who Vote Up or Down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139146/revealing-identity-of-those-who-vote-up-or-down/139147#139147)

Comment: I have found that reporting anything to the mods is useless, no offense Christ but its a fact that I have observed first hand. If you report someone they know or are friends with, you are SOL. I can't tell you how I know but I know for a fact. If people were not anonymous in their voting, then they would be less likely to be purposely vengeful and/or destructive in their goal to mothball someone's legitimate question because they know they can be publicly held accountable for bad behavior. This would deter trolling. After all if you do something, you should stand by your action or don't do it.

Comment: I, personally, would like to know if any of the high-ranking members of StackOverflow, those for whom I have a great deal of respect, like Jon Skeet, have ever upvoted any of my posts.

Comment: ' I can't tell you how I know but I know for a fact'.....you understand that argument is next-to-useless?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

No, voting is by design anonymous. Not even [♦ moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131317/295232) have access to information on individual votes.

The only way you will find out who voted for you is if someone decides to leave a comment saying so and maybe their reason. This doesn't mean they couldn't be lying also.

(To tell if, and how, you voted on a specific post, your votes are stored in a database. And of course [Stack Exchange employees do have access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758) to that information, but it's only used in exceptional circumstances, such as investigating voting fraud.)

Answer (score 70):

No. Voting is anonymous.

Answer (score 20):

By design, the site has anonymous voting. [Except for developers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758), NO ONE has access to viewing such things, not even moderators. Having voting made public would cause nothing but problems

1. Users may bug others about down votes they gave out
2. Who needs to know up votes? You just got +10, what more could you ask for?

Comment: 3. If someone know that you upvoted something, he could theorically pay you (unlikely to happen on SE sites, but real votations are secret because of that).
Where "real" means "elections in countries" (I don't pretend to say SE votes are not real XD)