# How do I find out who voted on my question or answer?

Tags: support, questions, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who both up/down voted your answer/question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question)

Is there any way for me to find who voted up or voted down my questions or answers?

Comment: Same as: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there isn't.

Voting is supposed to be anonymous - to prevent retribution for down-votes is one of the reasons.

If someone wants to be non-anonymous they will leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This might be available in the CC dumps.. but I personally think it should be left anonymous so you can't vote-retaliate or collude :)

Comment: voting is anonymized in the cc dumps

Comment: hence indicating "might" - never went through the dumps myself