# Seeing the list of users who voted on my posts

Tags: support, users, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who both up/down voted your answer/question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question)

I want to find out the list of users who have voted on my posts.

Some users leave comments saying -1 or +1 (for some reason) while those who don't comment leave me guessing who's voting on my posts. Downvotes without comments also don't help me figure out what is wrong with my question or answer. But I'm not saying all downvotes need to have comments.

So how do I find out the users that have voted on my posts?

Comment: What is more - how would knowing who did it tell you what you did wrong? It's not as if each user only ever has one reason why they downvote.

Comment: And what would you do *if* you knew?

Comment: @Arjen, to start a war I guess :P On a serious note, it's human nature to want to know, though we managed to curb it here.

Comment: Stop making lists for single item points. It's like you don't know why bullets are used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Voting is anonymous [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question).

And I guess, its to avoid extra conflicts / misunderstandings between members.

Comment: And rightly so. There would be *war* if we could see each other's downvotes.