# Who voted for or against

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)

Is there a way to see who voted up or down on my question or answer?

Comment: Nope. (15 chars)

Comment: Though it's generally recommended that you leave a comment if you are going to downvote a post.

Comment: If it's not too much of a bother. And you feel like it. And you actually have something useful to say. @Null.

Comment: The downvote is very funny  :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, all votes are anonymous. It does not matter who voted for what. Votes are an indication of *community* acceptance of an answer.

Comment: **Aside:** The team can find out, and there exist database processes which use that info to try to detect and correct cheating.

Comment: @dmckee absolutely correct. There is no way for a user *without* DB access to see the voters. Even moderators and "double-star" admins do not.

Comment: What are "double-star" admins?

Comment: @NullUser The old SE1.0 sites had 'double star' mods who acted as administrators to their own Stack Exchange Site.  See: http://mathoverflow.net/users/1/anton-geraschenko