# Need to know about question and answer vote up by user?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who both up/down voted your answer/question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question)

I think we should have right to know that which user voted up and voted down.

So, is there any way so get to know that which user voted up and down our question and answer?

Comment: Why do you care?

Comment: @Cody **So I can go to the *****er's house and whoop his ass!**

Comment: @Pekka - my thoughts exactly =) On an entirely unrelated note, I feel your "Location" in your profile should be "Under the Bridge", isn't that where all trolls live? ;-)

Comment: @Rob good point! Updated.

Answer (score 9):

NO. There is no way to know which user up/downvoted you on SE sites.

There have been lot of requests on this regard, but keeping the up/down votes anonymous is the best choice for the SE sites. This would keep the emotions like favourism and hatred as far as possible from the site. Also this is about upvoting the questions and answers, and not concerned with users. So you should really not bother about **WHO** voted you, rather check **WHY**.

Answer (score 4):

No, no, no and no. Allowing people to see *who* has upvoted/downvoted their questions/answers adds no value to the site. When I'm reading a post regarding a feature request on meta.stackoverflow and considering whether it's good or bad, I consider the following:

- Would the feature improve the quality of questions asked?
- Would the feature improve the quality of answers asked?
- Would the feature improve the user experience?

I can't see a way that this would be a *yes* to the first two, and only tenuously a *yes* to the final point and then only because it would allow users to easily discover patterns of "malicious" downvoting. Remember, votes should be given (either up or down) based on **the quality of the question/answer, not because of who posted the question/answer** (unless it's a question/answer from Jon Skeet ;-). The last bit wasn't meant seriously, by the way :)

In other words, the only possible use I can see for this is to allow users to easily detect patterns of abuse in votes that a given user has been making. There are at least two mechanisms in play for this to be resolved already:

1. Automated processes that detect patterns of abuse (targeted up-voting and targeted down-voting) and cancel the votes.
2. The facility to mail team@stackoverflow.com / flag for moderator attention if a user believes they're the target of serial up/down voting to request its review.

Therefore, there's really no "added value" to the site in providing this feature.