# How can i found that which user has give me up vote or down vote?

Tags: discussion, voting, users

can i know which user has give me up vote or down vote ? because in general case some developer give a down vote with out reason.

Comment: Votes are anonymous. Period.

Comment: see, 3 down vote.may be that is duplicate but at least developer should not give directly down vote.

Comment: guys this is my first question on meta.:(

Comment: Why should developers not have the right to downvote, especially when they're the ones who wrote the system in the first place?

Comment: @Lucifer its mistake dude.:P

Comment: Also, [downvotes are different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).  I would imagine that even if a couple of the downvotes are due to lack of research effort a lot of the rest are "OMG DON'T MAKE THIS A FEATURE".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can never find that out, unless the user tells you themselves. Votes on Stack Overflow are totally anonymous. Even moderators can't see who has voted for you. They can, however, see the voting patterns.

So the conclusion is: It is impossible to see who has voted on your post ( question/answer ).

An update from [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90758/214722) developers of SE can see this part.

Comment: from my question, you get highest reputation in single answer :P