# I want to know who upvoted a particular post

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)

I think it's currently not possible to find this out; but I've observed that some friends are using SO as a group and voting for group members for the sake of reputation. By this I mean that even answers that are not suitable for particular questions are up voted many times. This makes it hard for question askers to know which one to select.

So I'm suggesting that it should be possible to know who has upvoted individual posts.