# Are +1's anonymous?

Tags: support, voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)

Is there any way for someone to find out who +1 a question or an answer?

Comment: In that case...

Comment: Why are you guys so mean? Double negative? I just wanted to know who +1'd one of my questions. Should I have contacted support, I thought this was the kind of question meta was for.

Comment: Votes on meta mean agreement/disagreement. People want votes to remain anonymous.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, voting on posts is anonymous.

Unless someone tells you explicitly that they voted, there is no way of finding out. Even moderators (diamonds next to their name) do not know who voted.

Theoretically, Stack Exchange employees can find out, as they have access to the underlying database, but as far as we know there is no UI that'll let anyone see voting breakdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Votes are anonymous.

You can try to figure out who downvoted your question by correlating the exact time of the downvote with anyone who's reputation went down by 1 at the same time.

Comment: And that's then just speculation and circumstantial evidence at best.

Comment: True, though even if someone tells you they voted, they might be fibbing ;)

Comment: Exactly! I totally voted for your answer, of course! :-P

Comment: Is this not possible to find out using data.stackexchange? based on your answers I assume not, but how is that?

Comment: @iight The data in Data Explorer is pretreated to remove this kind of information before being made available.