# where can i ask for statistics?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, up-votes, statistics, personal-statistics

> All i need to know is from

1. where can i see whose **viewed my profile**?
2. where can i see whose **downvote and upvoted my question and
   answere**?
3. where can i see whose **viewed my questions**?

> Is there a feature in **stackoverflow** so user can find above
> information.

Comment: 1. Nowhere, 2. Nowhere, 3. Nowhere. The voting is private for good reasons, tracking who viewed the questions or profiles, why bother?

Comment: just for information brother because everyone giving such feature including Facebook not by themselves but through third party apps.

Comment: @DanielFischer see this is the reason bro people come and down vote it without knowing answer because sometime user came who don't know answer at all but still they down vote that question because they don't know the answer.

Comment: @DipeshParmar that's quite a lot of assumptions right there. Fact is, without an admission of the user you can't know why you were voted up or down. And with all the previous discussions on the subject here, voting is most likely going to remain anonymous.

Comment: Repeat after me: Stack Overflow is not a Social Network.

Comment: If people are upvoting / downvoting your questions suspiciously (such as the same person always downvoting you) then that would be tracked and picked up by the moderators and the general site audits 'behind-the-scenes' so if you're concerned about serial downvoters then that's a separate issue that is already able to be managed.

Comment: Half duplicate: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984/187824)

Comment: @DipeshParmar You do realize that Facebook apps which purport to show who has visited your profile are all scams, right? (I guess not...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Addressed individually:

> where I can see who has viewed my profile

You can't. As far as I know this information is not even recorded beyond the server logs. There's no reason to show it. Stack Overflow is not a social network.

> where I can see who has downvoted and upvoted my questions and answers?

You can't. Voting is private. Users need to be able to use their votes as they see fit based on the quality of the post they're voting on without worrying about confrontation. They have an option to leave a comment to explain their vote, but it's just that - an option. The only people that can see your votes are developers, and they have to work rather hard to get it. That's how it was designed.

> where I can see who has viewed my questions?

You can't. Similar to profile views, this data isn't interesting in the context of asking and answering questions. This would be useful for a site like Facebook or Linkedin where the focus is deliberately placed on ephemera.

We share and curate programming knowledge, no more - no less. Take a look at the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites), it's a pretty nice summary of how the site works and a rather comprehensive list of features, just broken down into small pieces that are easy to digest.

Comment: **Stack Overflow is not a social network** that kills it

Answer (score 12):

> 1. where I can see who has **viewed my profile**?
> 2. where I can see who has **downvoted and upvoted my questions and
>    answers**?
> 3. where I can see who has **viewed my questions**?

### Nowhere.

Voting is private on Stack Exchange. And I don't see any reason behind seeing who viewed my profile and posts.

If it would be a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), I am sure it would be [declined](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/Img/team/Nick%20Craver.gif)

Comment: I re-tagged this as support, as I don't think he's proposing the feature.

Comment: @TimPost - You haven't re-tagged yet....

Comment: Weird, I did actually. Did it again, appears to have taken.

Comment: @TimPost - Now it is updated. :)