# How to contact other users and what is the origin of my upvotes on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

I recently became a bit more active on Stack Overflow and now have a few questions which I couldn't find in the FAQ:

- Can I see who upvoted an answer or comment of mine?
- Can I send a message to a user from his profile?
- Where should I ask these kind of questions? ;)

Comment: You may want to consider more descriptive titles to your questions, considering meta.stackoverflow is *all* about questions about stackoverflow. =)

Comment: agreed ... wasn't that clearheaded when posting this :)

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to lump multiple questions into a question post. Your questions have all been asked previously, but we can't close this as a duplicate of multiple questions.

Comment: @AlEverett: if we collaborate we can; half of us close as dupe of one, the other close it as a dupe of another. :-)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12984)

Comment: this made me smile :) you need to collaborate to close a question? ;) .. makes me feel important :) .... i will just delete this question, that's probably the best way :)

Comment: hmm i can not delete this because it already has an answer ... sorry : no garbage cleaning it seems ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to add to the existing answer:

1. No - explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)
2. No - But some users  list how to contact them through other means (via twitter, mail etc) in their profile description. That's all
3. You posted here, which is the right place, but I think if you searched a bit, you may have got the answers without asking this question.

Comment: 1. thanks ... 2. thanks ... 3. i searched on stackoverflow, then tried to post there, which automagically sent me here to ask, i forgot to search here as well, sorry :)

Comment: Searching... [google is there](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=who+upvoted%2Fdownvoted+my+post+in+stackoverflow&oq=who+upvoted%2Fdownvoted+my+post+in+stackoverflow&sugexp=chrome,mod=6&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 4):

This is the place to ask such meta questions, but you may want to search for previous posts on the subjects first. Specifically, look through the [Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) post for commonly asked questions.

- No, votes are anonymous, you cannot see who voted.
- No, this is not a social network, you cannot send messages

Comment: thanks for your answer. i searched the stackoverflow faq, but couldnt find anything there. i then tried to ask the question there, and was sent here